# perfrormance dip when playing youtube on surface go 2

Tags: google-chrome, performance, surface, video-streaming

I've installed Ubuntu 23.10 GNOME on my Surface Go 2 because Windows 11 is way too slow.
I only use it to watch youtube and occasionally stream simple games from my main desktop with parsec.

it worked mostly but the only issue I have is a big difference in performance compared to W11 when playing YouTube videos:
On Windows 1080p is a breeze and it can even play 4k if you wait a little bit.
On Ubuntu 1080p constantly skips frames and stutters (with CPU usage stuck at 100%) while 4k is not watchable at all.
from what I found it seems to be a problem with hardware acceleration? I'm not sure.

Does anyone know a fix for this or should I use a different browser? (if possible I'd rather not)

Comment: it's 23.10 mb  :)

Answer (score 0):

just use Firefox.
that seems to be the only solution rn.